# SVGedit: how to remove all elements from svgCanvas?

Tags: svg-edit

How to remove all elements from svgCanvas ?

I tried with :

```
svgCanvas.clearSvgContentElement()
svgCanvas.clearSelection();
```

With no success. (and if possible avoid blinking effect)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `svgCanvas.clear()`